# Headings Element in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, html-heading

I have a website that running OK at Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. But in Internet Explorer, it won't show the title of paragraph. I use Headings Elements like H1, H2 and so on. But in Internet Explorer it won't show up. How it could be?

```
h2 {
margin:8px 0;
margin-top:-10px;
padding:8px 0;
font-size:26px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:1.2em;
color:#333;
text-transform:none;}
```

I use `<h2>Title of Book</h2>`  and above is my code.

Comment: Tried [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `margin: 8px 0` --- This will take margin as `8px` from top and bottom and `0` from right and left.

And again in the next line you are applying `margin-top : -10px.`

Maybe that is causing the problem.
Not sure but still you can try !!